# python 3.7 can't access google secret service manager

Tags: api, python-3.7, gcloud, google-secret-manager

I configured the required roles for the secret service manager, but when I try to access them through python 3.7 code I get error 403 access denied:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'secretmanager.secrets.list' denied for resource 'projects/projectid' (or it may not exist)
```

If I access them with command line it works:

```
gcloud secrets list
```

This is the python code:

```
# Build the resource name of the parent project.
parent = f"projects/projectid"

# Create the Secret Manager client.
client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

# List all secrets.
for secret in client.list_secrets(request={"parent": parent}):
    print("Found secret: {}".format(secret.name))
```

Comment: Are you replacing “projectid” with your project’s ID?

Comment: yes I am replacing it

Comment: Are you using App Default Credentials? Please include the service account's roles/permissions. Did you remember to **export** `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`?

Comment: It works now but I cannot get the content of the secret with this code I get attribute error:
sec = client.get_secret_version(request={"name": "projects/code/secrets/MYSECRET/versions/latest"})
print(sec.payload)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me.

```sh
BILLING="..."
PROJECT="..."
ACCOUNT="..."
SECRET="test"

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

gcloud services enable secretmanager.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

EMAIL="${ROBOT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL}

# See note: the minimum role that includes the perm to list secrets
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/secretmanager.viewer

echo "test" > test
gcloud secrets create ${SECRET} \
--data-file="test" \
--project=${PROJECT}

python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

python3 -m pip install google-cloud-secret-manager

# Both required by the app
export PROJECT
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json

python main.py
```

Yields:

```
Found secret: projects/12345678912/secrets/test
```

main.py:

```py
from google.cloud import secretmanager

import os

project=os.getenv("PROJECT")

client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

parent = f"projects/{project}"

secrets = client.list_secrets(request={
    "parent":parent,
})

for secret in secrets:
    print("Found secret: {}".format(secret.name))
```

> **NOTE** `roles/secretmanager.viewer` is the only predefined role that includes the permission necessary to list `secretmanager.secrets.list` ([link](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control))